# C# run same MessageBox 2 time in Timer Tick

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, timer, messagebox

I read time from php with C#. I have to show MessageBox before Logoff windows when the time is equal. But when I run program it show same MessageBox 2 time. I want to show MessageBox 1 time only before Logoff. I set Interval is 30,000. How to do it? This is my code

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool showingBox = false;
            timer1.Start();
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://172.22.22.20/time.php");
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            //textBox1.Text = content;

            if (showingBox) return;
            showingBox = true;
            try
            {

                if (content == "08:00")
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(new Form() { TopMost = true }, "11111");  // This will show 2 Message Box when time = 08.00

                }
            }
            finally
            {
                showingBox = false;
            }

            if (content == "08:05")
            {

                ExitWindowsEx(4, 0);

            }

            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i understand your question right, but could it be that you start the timer twice ?
As far as i can see you do start the timer again in your timer_tick method

```
   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool showingBox = false;
            timer1.Start(); // <-- second time startet.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you using **timer1.Start();** in timer1_Tick Event?

Answer (score 0):

I remove **timer1.Start()** but it also show twice messagebox . I change the code like this **flag = true;** have to run before show message box . Now it work!!.

```
      if (content == "10:09")
      {
          if (!flag)
          {
              flag = true;
              MessageBox.Show(new Form() { TopMost = true }, "11111" +flag);

          }
      }
```